# divide the multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an initial array:

```
array
( [no] => array 
          (
             [<30] => 3
             [>30] => 5
             [>50] => 2
          )
  [yes] => array
          (
             [<30] => 4
             [>30] => 2
             [>50] => 7
          ) 
  [maybe] => array
          (
             [<30] => 7
             [>30] => 9
             [>50] => 10
          ) 
)
```

whether the above array can be split into multiple array variables by yes, no and maybe. such as :

```
$yes = array(3,5,2);
$no = array(4,2,7);
$maybe = array(7,9,10);
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
$result = array();

foreach($data as $response)
    $result[] = array_values($response);

list($no, $yes, $maybe) = $result;
```

Where `$data` is the array shown in your question.

You can then access the 3 values from `$no`, `$yes`, and `$maybe` assuming that the order of `$data` is respective to that order.

Comment: It depends on key order in original array, which can change over time.

Answer (score 1):

```
$yes   = $array['yes'];
$no    = $array['no'];
$maybe = $array['maybe'];
```

That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the inner arrays were populated in the same orders for the same keys, it looks like you want to take a look at array_values: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

And from that, it should be simple to do:

```
$yes   = array_values( $initial_array['yes'] );
$no    = array_values( $initial_array['no'] );
$maybe = array_values( $initial_array['maybe'] );
```

Answer (score 0):

All the other solution given for this question depends on the name of the key, if the key changes from `yes` to `YES`, none of the solution works, Here is the dynamic solution for it, simple too.

```
$array   = array("yes"=>array(1,2,3,4),"no"=>array(3,45,6,),"maybe"=>array(7,8,9));

foreach($array as $key=>$val){
   $key      = strtolower($key);
   $$key     = $val;
}

print_r($yes);
echo "<br>";
print_r($no);
echo "<br>";
print_r($maybe);
```

Comment: If the data is indeed dynamic (say is provided by a third party service), then if they change the key case from "yes" to "YES" and your variable is $yes, your code will still break ($yes is not $YES). Some mitigation would be to lowercase the keys prior to creating named local variables "foreach($array as $key=>$val){$key = strtolower($key);$$key = $val;}"